# Issue with Merge in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me resolve this type error? I am running the following code. I am trying to merge two dataframes on the column "Issue_Year"

```
data_locked = data_locked.merge(rate_data_t.iloc[1],on = "Issue_Year",how='left')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
   File "C:\Users\ED397JT\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_38396/1094145651.py", line 1, in <module>
        data_locked = data_locked.merge(rate_data_t.iloc[1],on = "Issue_Year",how='left')
    
      File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9186, in merge
        return merge(
    
      File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 107, in merge
        op = _MergeOperation(
    
      File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 700, in __init__
        ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    
      File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1092, in _get_merge_keys
        right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    
      File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
        raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'Issue_Year'
```

I converted both of those columns to floats. The other columns are objects. The dataframes are different sizes, but that should not matter since we are doing a left join.

does anyone have an idea as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

merge is `dataframe` to `dataframe` but `iloc[]` return `series` adding `[]`

```
data_locked = data_locked.merge(rate_data_t.iloc[[1]],on = "Issue_Year",how='left')
```

Comment: You can actually merge a Series (cf. [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)), but it needs to have a name (and obviously match the `on` if used)